# Weird Nan loss for custom Keras loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement a custom loss in Keras but can't get it to work.

I have implemented it in numpy and with keras.backend:

```py
def log_rmse_np(y_true, y_pred):
    d_i = np.log(y_pred) -  np.log(y_true)
    loss1 = (np.sum(np.square(d_i))/np.size(d_i))
    loss2 = ((np.square(np.sum(d_i)))/(2 * np.square(np.size(d_i))))
    loss = loss1 - loss2
    print('np_loss =  %s - %s = %s'%(loss1, loss2, loss))
    return loss

def log_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    d_i = (K.log(y_pred) -  K.log(y_true))
    loss1 = K.mean(K.square(d_i))
    loss2 = K.square(K.sum(K.flatten(d_i),axis=-1))/(K.cast_to_floatx(2) * K.square(K.cast_to_floatx(K.int_shape(K.flatten(d_i))[0])))
    loss = loss1 - loss2
    return loss
```

When I test and compare the losses with the following function everything seems to work just fine.

```py
def check_loss(_shape):
    if _shape == '2d':
        shape = (6, 7)
    elif _shape == '3d':
        shape = (5, 6, 7)
    elif _shape == '4d':
        shape = (8, 5, 6, 7)
    elif _shape == '5d':
        shape = (9, 8, 5, 6, 7)

    y_a = np.random.random(shape)
    y_b = np.random.random(shape)

    out1 = K.eval(log_rmse(K.variable(y_a), K.variable(y_b)))
    out2 = log_rmse_np(y_a, y_b)

    print('shapes:', str(out1.shape), str(out2.shape))
    print('types: ', type(out1), type(out2))
    print('log_rmse:    ', np.linalg.norm(out1))
    print('log_rmse_np: ', np.linalg.norm(out2))
    print('difference:  ', np.linalg.norm(out1-out2))
    assert out1.shape == out2.shape
    #assert out1.shape == shape[-1]

def test_loss():
    shape_list = ['2d', '3d', '4d', '5d']
    for _shape in shape_list:
        check_loss(_shape)
        print ('======================')

test_loss()
```

The above code prints:

```py
np_loss =  1.34490449177 - 0.000229461787517 = 1.34467502998
shapes: () ()
types:  <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
log_rmse:     1.34468
log_rmse_np:  1.34467502998
difference:   3.41081509703e-08
======================
np_loss =  1.68258448859 - 7.67580654591e-05 = 1.68250773052
shapes: () ()
types:  <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
log_rmse:     1.68251
log_rmse_np:  1.68250773052
difference:   1.42057615005e-07
======================
np_loss =  1.99736933814 - 0.00386228512295 = 1.99350705302
shapes: () ()
types:  <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
log_rmse:     1.99351
log_rmse_np:  1.99350705302
difference:   2.53924863358e-08
======================
np_loss =  1.95178217182 - 1.60006871892e-05 = 1.95176617114
shapes: () ()
types:  <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
log_rmse:     1.95177
log_rmse_np:  1.95176617114
difference:   3.78277884572e-08
======================
```

I never get an exception when I compile and fit my model with this loss and when I run the model with the 'adam'-loss everything works fine.
However with this loss keras keeps showing a nan-loss:

```py
Epoch 1/10000
 17/256 [>.............................] - ETA: 124s - loss: nan
```

Kind of stuck here... Am I doing something wrong?

Using Tensorflow 1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

**Update:**

After a suggestion by Marcin Możejko I updated the code but unfortunately the training loss is still Nan:

```py
def get_log_rmse(normalization_constant):
    def log_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        d_i = (K.log(y_pred) -  K.log(y_true))
        loss1 = K.mean(K.square(d_i))
        loss2 = K.square(K.sum(K.flatten(d_i),axis=-1))/K.cast_to_floatx(2 * normalization_constant ** 2)
        loss = loss1 - loss2
        return loss
    return log_rmse
```

Then the model is compiled via:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=get_log_rmse(batch_size))
```

**Update 2:**

The model summary looks like this:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 160, 256, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 160, 256, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 160, 256, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 80, 128, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 80, 128, 128)      73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 80, 128, 128)      147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 40, 64, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 40, 64, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 40, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 40, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 40, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 20, 32, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 20, 32, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 20, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 20, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 20, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 10, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 10, 16, 128)       1048704   
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling2 (None, 20, 32, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DTr (None, 20, 32, 64)        131136    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_6 (UpSampling2 (None, 40, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DTr (None, 40, 64, 32)        32800     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_7 (UpSampling2 (None, 80, 128, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2DTr (None, 80, 128, 16)       8208      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_8 (UpSampling2 (None, 160, 256, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 160, 256, 1)       401       
=================================================================
Total params: 11,806,401
Trainable params: 11,806,401
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Update 3:**

Sample y_true:

[image: Sample of an input image:]

Comment: it may be due to the log function, if y_pre or y_true is 0 you are trying to calculate log(0) which is -inf, if you try np.log(0) - np.log(0) you get nan

Comment: Good point but I don't think that is the root of the problem since the data is between 0 and 1 and the nan-loss still persists after I add 1 to both y_true and y_pred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
K.cast_to_floatx(K.int_shape(K.flatten(d_i))[0]
```

as a loss function is compiled before any shape is provided - this expression evaluates to `None` and this where your error comes from. I tried to set `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape` but this didn't work also (probably due to the way `keras` compiles the model). I advice to set this number to a constant in the following manner:

```
def get_log_rmse(normalization_constant):
    def log_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        d_i = (K.log(y_pred) -  K.log(y_true))
        loss1 = K.mean(K.square(d_i))
        loss2 = K.square(
            K.sum(
                K.flatten(d_i),axis=-1))/(K.cast_to_floatx(
                    2 * normalization_constant ** 2) 
        loss = loss1 - loss2
        return loss
    return log_rmse
```

and then compile:

```
model.compile(..., loss=get_log_rmse(normalization_constant))
```

I guess that `normalization_constant` is equal to a `batch_size` but I'm not sure so I've made it generic.

**Update:**

After a suggestion by Marcin Możejko I updated the code but unfortunately the training loss is still Nan:

```
def get_log_rmse(normalization_constant):
    def log_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        d_i = (K.log(y_pred) -  K.log(y_true))
        loss1 = K.mean(K.square(d_i))
        loss2 = K.square(K.sum(K.flatten(d_i),axis=-1))/K.cast_to_floatx(2 * normalization_constant ** 2)
        loss = loss1 - loss2
        return loss
    return log_rmse
```

Then the model is compiled via:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=get_log_rmse(batch_size))
```

**Update 2:**

The model definition looks like this:

```
input_shape = (160, 256, 3)
print('Input_shape: %s'%str(input_shape))
base_model = keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
                               input_tensor=None, input_shape=input_shape, 
                               pooling=None, # None, 'avg', 'max'
                               classes=1000)
for i in range(5):
    base_model.layers.pop()
base_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)
print('VGG19 output_shape: ' + str(base_model.output_shape))

x = Deconv(128, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(base_model.output)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Deconv(64, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Deconv(32, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Deconv(16, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding='same')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable! Unfortunately i still get nan-loss after implementing your suggestion. Updated the Question to show the code you suggested.

Comment: Are you sure that your `y_true` and `y_pred` are not equal to `0` then? In my case - it worked on random data.

Comment: Also in my case it works on the randomly generated data in the test method if i replace the direct method call with `out1 = K.eval(get_log_rmse(batch_size)(K.variable(y_a), K.variable(y_b)))`. The keras fit() function still shows me nan-values though... :( Also if i add 1 (or 1000) to the input (y_true, y_pred) i get nan.

Comment: Which is weird because the input is a grayscale image scaled to 0-1.

Comment: Could you provide a model definition?

Comment: Your output is not squashed to `(0, 1)`. The last layer has a linear activation. Another thing - could you print out a `model.summary()`? (Another thing - you are editing my answer - not your question)

Comment: Oh god sorry... :D

Comment: Ok the edits are now in my question and I added a summary. Hope this helps!

Comment: So - try to change your activation to `sigmoid`. Now you have a `linear` one which is unbounded.

Comment: Still nan-loss :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you print out an example `y_true`?

Comment: As an image you mean? Sure!

Comment: And values. Especially `min` and `max` of an image.

Comment: Original min  and max are 0 and 255 but are scaled to 0-1 in preprocessing.

Comment: Are there any `0` values?

Comment: Yes but adding 1/255, 1, 1000 to y_true and y_pred in the loss function does not solve the problem.

Comment: To be honest `0` values are very improbable but could theoretically happen!

Comment: Even after adding `sigmoid`?

Comment: yep... :( what else could be the problem? Could it make a difference that i use fit_generator()?

Comment: This is the generator I'm using:  `def train_generator():
    while True:
        tup = next(zip(scene_train_generator, depth_train_generator))
        samples = tup[0][0]
        results = tup[1][0]
        yield samples, results`

Comment: Have you tried:  `d_i = (K.log(1 + y_pred) -  K.log(1 + y_true))`

Comment: Yes I did. Still nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163284/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-raspel).

Answer (score 1):

Try fitting your model on a built in loss for a few epochs. And then compile your model again, using your own loss. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

When I get the same error with `root mean square percentage error` =  `k.sqrt(K.mean(K.square( (y_true - y_pred) / y_true )))`

Solution :
I removed the denominator and ran for couple of epochs. Then stopped and ran with original equation. It started giving finite loss values.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar loss function and was getting `nan` as loss.

```
def log_rsme(y_true, y_pred):
    loga = tf.math.log(y_true)
    logb = tf.math.log(y_pred)
    error = tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.square(loga - logb))
    return error
```

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
def log_rsme(y_true, y_pred):
    loga = tf.math.log(y_true + 0.000001)
    logb = tf.math.log(y_pred + 0.000001)
    error = tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.square(loga - logb))
    return error
```

Since `log` is not defined for non-positive values, it is always better to ensure that the domain of `log` is never violated. In my case, the last layer of my model had a `relu` activation ensuring non-negative values, but it allowed zero as a possible value. So in order to eliminate such cases, I added a small constant i.e. 0.000001 which fixed this `nan` problem.